# Why Nuxt Middleware context is undefined?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, middleware

I am trying to get *user agent* in Nuxt middleware. And using the example from nuxtjs.org

**middleware/user_agent.js**

```
export default function (context) {
 
  context.userAgent = process.server
    ? context.req.headers['user-agent']
    : navigator.userAgent;

  console.log(context.userAgent)
}
```

I get error *cannot read property of undefined.*

Cant figure out why its undefined...

Comment: How do you use this specific middleware? Also, keep in mind that this one will have `process.server` truthy only once (on initial render).

Comment: i dont have good understanding about context even reading docs. the middleware gets called on initial request and nuxt routes - no problem here. process.server works properly also. but cant get anything from context... read docs 10 times

Comment: The context is the Nuxt context with Vue router, Vuex, i18n or alike. Nothing related to what you're looking for IMO. Here is a link: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/ Can you get the use agent from a server context or is it browser only?

Comment: As from docs "The context provides additional objects/params from Nuxt to Vue components and is available in special nuxt lifecycle areas like asyncData , fetch , plugins , ***middleware*** and nuxtServerInit". And still its undefined.

Comment: I need to get userAgent and nothing seems to work!

Comment: I'm not sure what to fetch that from on the server side (will need to double check in front of my computer) but let's focus on 2 things first: 1. can you achieve to make it work on every client side navigation? (I assume you need the user agent for every one of your pages, tell me if it's not the case) 2. can you successfully console log from there and do you see the user agent in that case?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. i see console.log(navigator.userAgent) no problem from devTools. But frustrates me that this seems it should be obvious but I cant see:/ Also route, store works no problem

Comment: thx @kissu for time. middleware function vars are nothing more than context destructuring (palm head slap:)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware#middleware-directory), you will have everything for a working User Agent from the server and the client (I just tried it).

Don't forget to add that to your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  ...
  router: {
    middleware: 'user-agent',
  },
}
```

Also don't forget that the initial call will happen on the server, and that your possible `console.log` will be in your shell (and not in your browser's console)

[image]